# Get Records from table where quantity is not between fromquantity and ToQuantity using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a two table with following `tb_Types` and `tb_TypePrices`:

```
tb_Type
-------
id
title

tb_TypePrices
-------------
id
typeId
fromQuantity
ToQuantity
Supplier
Price
```

these tables has parent child relationship

Now I want to fetch data from `tb_Types` join with `tb_TypePrices` where `typeId=mytypeId` and `parameterQuantity` is NOT between `fromQuantity` and `ToQuantity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from t in tb_Type
join tp in tb_TypePrices on t.id equals tp.typeId
where t.id == mytypeId && 
      (parameterQuantity < tp.fromQuantity ||
       tp.ToQuantity < parameterQuantity)
select new { Type = t, TypePrice = tp }
```

Or if you want all filtered type prices in one object:

```
from t in tb_Type
join tp in tb_TypePrices on t.id equals tp.typeId into g
where t.id == mytypeId         
select new { 
    Type = t, 
    Prices = g.Where(x => parameterQuantity < x.fromQuantity ||
                          x.ToQuantity < parameterQuantity) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var data = from t1 in tb_Type
           join t2 in tb_TypePrices
           on t1.id equals t2.typeId
           where t2.fromQuantity < parameterQuantity || t2.ToQuantity > parameterQuantity
           select new { Type = t1, TypePrices = t2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have foreign key relations then you should be able to use

```
var query = tb_TypePrices
     .Where( t => t.fromQuantity < parameterQuantity || 
                  t.ToQuantity > parameterQuantity)
     .Select( t => new 
         { 
             t.fromQuantity, 
             t.ToQuantity,
             ... etc,
             Title=t.tb_Type.title 
         };
```